# Update records in table with variable Python sqlite

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

```
def CheckUpdateUser(self, usernameC, passwordC, usernameE, passwordE, edit_account_window):
    usernameC = usernameC.get()
    passwordC = passwordC.get()
    usernameE = usernameE.get()
    passwordE = passwordE.get()
    if len(usernameC) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please Enter Current Credentials. \n\nIf issue persists contact an Admin or try again.")
    elif len(usernameE) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please Enter New Credentials. \n\nIf issue persists contact an Admin or try again.")
    else:
        with sqlite3.connect("library.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT password from loginUsers WHERE username = ? and password = ?", (usernameC, passwordC))
            username_search = cursor.fetchone()
            if not username_search is None:
               # self.updateUserInDatabase
                cursor.execute("UPDATE loginUsers SET username = ? and password = ? WHERE username = ?", (usernameE, passwordE, usernameC))                      
                messagebox.showinfo("Success!", "Credentials updated, you can now go back to login page and use the credentials you entered")        
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Error.", "User Not Found. \n\nContact an Admin to register an account or try again.")
```

Having trouble with the :

```
        with sqlite3.connect("library.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT password from loginUsers WHERE username = ? and password = ?", (usernameC, passwordC))
            username_search = cursor.fetchone()
            if not username_search is None:
               # self.updateUserInDatabase
                cursor.execute("UPDATE loginUsers SET username = ? and password = ? WHERE username = ?", (usernameE, passwordE, usernameC))                      
                messagebox.showinfo("Success!", "Credentials updated, you can now go back to login page and use the credentials you entered")
```

Section, I am using tkinter in Python, I am trying to update the current user info (username and password (usernameC, passwordC)) with new user info (username and password (usernameE, passwordE) .

usernameC and passwordC are both User inputted on this other part of the code :

```
    Label(edit_account_window, text='Current Username: ', bg = self.bgc, fg = "grey", font = "Arial").place(x=315, y=217)
    Label(edit_account_window, text='Current Password: ', bg = self.bgc, fg = "grey", font = "Arial").place(x=315, y=237)         
    Label(edit_account_window, text='New Username: ', bg = self.bgc, fg = "grey", font = "Arial").place(x=315, y=257)
    Label(edit_account_window, text='New Password: ', bg = self.bgc, fg = "grey", font = "Arial").place(x=315, y=277)

    usernameC = StringVar()
    passwordC = StringVar()

    usernameE = StringVar()
    passwordE = StringVar()

    Entry(edit_account_window, textvariable = usernameC, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=220)
    Entry(edit_account_window, show='*', textvariable = passwordC, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=240)
    Entry(edit_account_window, textvariable = usernameE, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=260)
    Entry(edit_account_window, show='*', textvariable = passwordE, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=280)

    edit_account_window_back = Button(edit_account_window, text=('Back'), width = 6, height = 1, bg = 'light grey', fg = 'black', font = ('Arial', 10), command=lambda:self.display(main_window))
    edit_account_window_back.place(x=27, y=750)

    updateB = Button(edit_account_window, text='UPDATE INFO', width = 11, command=lambda:self.CheckUpdateUser(usernameC, passwordC, usernameE, passwordE, main_window)) # This makes the register button, which will go to the CheckRegister def.
    updateB.place(x=472, y=300)
```

After checking that usernameC and passwordC are in loginUsers table, I want to update usernameC and passwordC with usernameE and passwordE .

HELP PLEASE!!

Comment: A) use an ORM. B) don't write your own authentication system. Good ones are dime a dozen C) do desktop apps need a username password anyway?

Comment: @e4c5 It's for a programming project, we need to use our own as the one above, how would I make the code above work? Thanks

Comment: you forgot to mention what the trouble was

Comment: @e4c5 The entered usernameC and passwordC (that match the username and password of a record in the loginUsers table in the database "library.db" don't update with usernameE and passwordE, I want the entered usernameC and passwordC to update to usernameE and passwordE

Comment: @RobertoMiguelPimentel, did you try doing `commit` after your `update` query?